# Convert Ensemble ID in gene symbol

Tags: r, biomart

I want to convert a list of 20K genes from Ensemble ID to gene symbol using R version 4.1.3. I am naive on using R.

I tried to download the following packages: "biomaRt" or "org.HS.eg.db", but everytime I get this error message:

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/piscadut/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘org.HS.eg.db’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: You have to install `biomaRt` through "Bioconductor". Try `install.packages("BiocManager")` first, then `BiocManager::install("biomaRt")`

Comment: The same applies for `org.HS.eg.db`almost all bioinformatics specific packages are distributed through bioconductor and not CRAn